# VESA:M92 standard, but ati driver installed? (12.04 LTS)

Tags: drivers, ati, video, dell, radeon

I have a Dell studio 1555 with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500, and I have installed the proprietary driver but when I go to settings>details>graphics, ubuntu tells me the driver is VESA:M92, experience: standard.

The driver has definitely installed correctly as I can get up the catalyst control centre and change settings which effect what I see. So is this just a false indication or am I not getting the full experience out of my video card?

Comment: Can anyone help with this? Things seem to be running okay but I would hate to think I wasn't getting the best performance out of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
```

I think it will show you that you are using the correct driver and so if you go to *Settings* → *Details* → *Graphics* and you see the **VESA:M92** driver, it is just an incorrect indication for a reason that I do not know, but I have the same issue here on my laptop.

Hope this helps.